# Xcode UILabel fit screen

Tags: xcode, uilabel

Hi quick question I'm want to allow my UILabel to auto adjust depending on what the phone, for example when I run my program on a iPhone 5 the labels fit perfectly but when simulating on a iPhone 6 label are still displaying at iPhone 5 size, do I need to adjust the constraint or implement a line of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are the best way to go with resizing,  there is no 1 line of code solution that will resize all of your labels depending on screen size unfortunately